# Else-if statement to hide div on z-index conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an overlay div that is hidden and set to display once either one of two buttons is clicked. I want to make it so that if one button is clicked, the element displays with a certain z-index, and if the same element is clicked again, the element will hide again. But if the element is visible and the second div is clicked I just want the z-index of the overlay to change, and of course if the second button is clicked again I want the overlay to disappear. I am trying to make this happen with an If Else statement and jQuery, here is the code. It is not working the way I want it to, as in I can make the overlay appear, but not disappear/change z-index as intended.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dot").click(function(){
      $(this).data("clicked", true);
  });

  $(".burgerMenu").click(function() {
    $(this).data("clicked", true);

    //Overlay Animation
    if ($(this).data("clicked") && $(".block").is(":visible")) {
      //alert("IT WORKS!");
      $(".block").css("z-index", "+1");
    } else if ($(this).data("clicked") && $(".block").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".block").css("z-index", "+1");
      $(".block").css("display", "block");
    } else if ($(this).data("clicked") && $(".block").css("z-index") > "-1") {
      $(".block").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      alert("Ah lads.");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* FAB SECTION */
.dot
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 200px;
}

#fab {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #6eadea;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 6px 10px 18px #686868;
}

#plusContain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#plus {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* DIALOGUE/MENU OVERLAY */

.block {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* BURGER MENU SECTION */

.burgerMenu {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.bar {
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

#top {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

#bottom {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="fab" class="dot dotDown">
  <div id=plusContain class="fab rotate">
    <div id="plus">+</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--MENU OVERLAY-->
<div id="overlay" class="block"></div>

<!--Burger-->
<div id="burger" class="burgerMenu">
  <div id="top" class="bar barTop"></div>
  <div id="middle" class="bar barMid"></div>
  <div id="bottom" class="bar barBot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question? Why is the irrelevant code supposed to help us? It simply confuses the issue making it harder for us to focus on where the problem is. Turn this into a [mcve]. Not even sure where the overlay is

Comment: Apologies, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on your post, sorry if not answering you correctly.

First the 'ifs', is `$(this).data("clicked")` inside them necesary? You are setting it to true with `$(this).data("clicked", true);` everytime before you start checking, so it's kinda redundant.

Then you check if `.block` is `visible`, or else if it's `hidden`, this would mean that you will never reach the third if.

My issue is that I do not fully understand what you are trying here. You want that when the burger is clicked an overlay appears keeping the burger still upfront, but the dot behind the overlay. When you click the burger again the overlay disappears and back to the start. I presume that the dot has the same behaviour as the burger.

If this is the behaviour you desire, then I would take a different approach more like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function modifyOverlay(new_z_index) {

        /** If the overlay is hidden, we just show it with the z-index we
          * get in new_z_index (new_z_index == 1 means that dot was clicked, 
          * new_z_index == 3 means that burger was clicked)
          */
        if ($(".block").is(":hidden")) {
     
            $(".block").css("display", "block");
            $(".block").css("z-index", new_z_index); // 1 or 3 

        } else if ($(".block").css("z-index") != new_z_index) {
        /** Because of the first if, we know that the overlay
          * is visible (which means it has z-index 1 or 3).
          * The only time the current z-index of the overlay will
          * be different from the new_z_index (this is what we are
          * checking on this if) is when you click the burger 
          * (new_z_index == 3) while the dot is also upfront 
          * (current overlay z-index == 1)
          */
       
            $(".block").css("z-index", new_z_index); // So we just set the z-index
                                                     // to new_z_index (which will 
                                                     // be 3) hidding the dot
        } else {
           /** If we get to this else, we know that the overlay is visible
             * (because of the first if) and we know that the current 
             * z-index is equal to the new_z_index (because of the second
             * if). 
             * So the possible cases are:
             * overlay's z-index is 3, and we pressed the burger (3)
             * or overlay's z-index is 1, and we pressed the dot (1),
             * both cases mean we hide the overlay
             */
            $(".block").css("display", "none");
            $(".block").css("z-index", "0");
        }
    }

    $(".dot").click(function(){
        //Overlay Animation
        modifyOverlay(1);
    });

    $(".burgerMenu").click(function() {
        //Overlay Animation
        modifyOverlay(3);
    });
});
```

```css
/* FAB SECTION */
.dot
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 200px;
}

#fab {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #6eadea;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 6px 10px 18px #686868;
    z-index: 2;
}

#plusContain {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#plus {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* DIALOGUE/MENU OVERLAY */

.block {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
    z-index: 0;
}


/* BURGER MENU SECTION */

.burgerMenu {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.bar {
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

#middle {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
}

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="fab" class="dot dotDown">
  <div id=plusContain class="fab rotate">
    <div id="plus">+</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--MENU OVERLAY-->
<div id="overlay" class="block"></div>

<!--Burger-->
<div id="burger" class="burgerMenu">
  <div id="top" class="bar barTop"></div>
  <div id="middle" class="bar barMid"></div>
  <div id="bottom" class="bar barBot"></div>
</div>
```

Changes on the snippet:

- `.block` has a z-index of 0.
- `.burgerMenu` has a z-index of -1.
- Added class `.upfront`.
- The javascript code has been reworked.

**EDIT:**

Changes on the snippet:

- `.burgerMenu` has a z-index of 4.
- `#fab` has a z-index of 2.
- Removed class `.upfront`.
- The javascript code has been reworked, comments were added for explanation purposes.

Comment: That is actually pretty close, and sorry if I wasn't able to explain very clearly. Your solution works as I would like, except that if the dot is clicked the overlay appears behind the dot And the burger, and if the burger is clicked after the dot has been the overlay adjusts to go above the dot.

Answer (score 1):

In your lines where you're incrementing the value of your z-index

```
$(".block").css("z-index", "+1");
```

You're setting the value of the z-index to be the value of positive 1.
Instead, this should be

```
$(".block").css("z-index", "+=1");
```

Similarly, to decrement the value

```
$(".block").css("z-index", "-=1");
```

Comment: No worries. Happy coding :)